# How to check WHO creates a certain contact

Tags: contacts, logs

I can´t see anywhere who is the creator of a particular contact in CRM. I can see the last update of that contact but not what user created which contact.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can find this information in the **Change Log** for the contact.

It will be the earliest entry in the change log.